# Laravel 5 Method [ALL] does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm trying to make a CRUD application in Laravel 5 to better understand how a php platform work ( first time using one ), but I keep getting the "Method [all] does not exist." error and I can't understand what i'm doing wrong. I have a table named 'products' in Mysql and what I'm trying to do, is to list all the entry's from within the table. I also have an index.blade.php that I will post if needed.

ProductsController.php

```
class ProductsController extends Controller {

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $products = ProductsController::all();

    return View::make('products.index')->with('products', $products);
}
```

Products.php

```
class Products extends Eloquent
{

}
```

routes.php

```
Route::resource('/', 'ProductsController@index');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Eloquent will assume the `User` model stores records in the `users` table. You may specify a custom table by defining a `$table` property on your model. [[Ref](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#basic-usage)]

So, you should rename your `Products.php` to `Product.php` (or define the `$table` property on your model).

Then you can retrieve all products:

```
$products = Product::all();
```

**Product.php**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model {

    //

}
```

**ProductsController.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Product;

class ProductsController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::all();

        return View::make('products.index')->with('products', $products);
    }

}
```

Comment: If I do this I get the error FatalErrorException in ProductsController.php line 17:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Product' not found

Comment: You should import the model: `use App\Product;`

Answer (score 1):

Why you write ProductsController to access all() function. To access all() function you must call Product model.

```
ProductsController::all();
```

**Example**

**Product Model**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'products';
}
```

**Product Controller**

```
class ProductController extends Controller {

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::all();

    return View::make('products.index')->with('products', $products);
}
```

Comment: If I do it like this I still get an error: FatalErrorException in ProductsController.php line 17:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Product' not found

Comment: Put 'use App\Product' inside the Product controller after namespace or call like this in Product COntroller 'App\Product::all();'